# Custom content for each qTip tooltip

Tags: jquery, qtip

I have a list of search results and for each one I want to be able to display more information about the result in question in a tooltip.

I have got as far as getting a qTip tooltip to appear when I rollover each a element but I don't understand how to get custom content into the tooltip for each result.

I guess this is largely because of my very limited jQuery knowledge.

In old style JavaScript I would pass a variable that was the tooltip content from the function call attached to the `<a>` tags. As there is no function call written in the `<a>` tag for jQuery tooltip it looks like this isn't the way to do it now.

Currently I have this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
       src="/assets/templates/unaexchange/js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tooltip").qtip({
   content: 'this is the content',
   position: {
      corner: {
         target: 'topRight',
         tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
      }
   }
});
});
```

And then the body has `<a class="tooltip">Link</a>` and then I have the standard :

```
<div class="qtip qtip-stylename">
  <div class="qtip-tip" rel="cornerValue"></div>
  <div class="qtip-wrapper">
    <div class="qtip-borderTop"></div> 
             <!-- Only present when using rounded corners-->
    <div class="qtip-contentWrapper">
        <div class="qtip-title"> 
             <!-- All CSS styles...-->
        <div class="qtip-button"></div> 
             <!-- ...are usually applied...-->
    </div>
    <div class="qtip-content">an attempt at standard content ?></div> 
             <!-- ...to these three elements!-->
  </div>
  <div class="qtip-borderBottom"></div> 
             <!-- Only present when using rounded corners-->
  </div>
</div>
```

But this isn't being displayed and I don't know how to create a specific chunk of HTML for each tooltip.

Is my approach wrong?

Should I create all the individual tooltips containing the custom content with separate IDs and then pick these IDs up and display or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can omit the content property to use the title of the `<a>` tag:

```
// use title attribute
$(".tooltip").qtip({
    position: {
        corner: {
            target: 'topRight',
            tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
        }
    }
});
```

or you can use a jquery selector. for example:

```
// use jquery selector
$(".tooltip2").each(function() {

    var content = $($(this).attr("href")).html();

    $(this).qtip({
        content: content,
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'topRight',
                tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Example** here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felixsigl/Gt9s4/)

Comment: Hi, This is really helpful, thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. My only problem with it is that I need to be able to click these links as well as have a tooltip on hover so the href can't be #foo. WOuld this be possible?

Comment: just use another attribute like `rel` containing the id of the content div

Comment: Worked breat, thanks very much for the help. I've learned a bit more about jquery in the process too.

Comment: Think I;'ve done it now. Sorry new to that aspect of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `title` attribute to each DOM element with the tooltip content that you want.  E.g.,

`<span class='tooltip' title='This will show up as a tooltip'>Whatever your markup happens to be</span>`

or

`<a class='tooltip' href='#' title='Another tooltip'>Some link</a>`

The `title` attribute is [standard in HTML 5 for all DOM elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-title-attribute).